# How to send a chat message of type 'announcement' to a Teams Channel via Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to send a `chatMessage` of type 'announcement' to a Teams channel. However, I receive the following error message:

> Attachment Id missing from the body.

Since the attachment id is read-only, I first tried to omit it. When I received the error, I tried to set a random id in the attachment and add this also to the body's content. In both cases I do receive the same error.

I have not found any example that shows how to send an announcement to a channel, so I hope to find help here.

I'm using PowerShell and the *Microsoft.Graph* module, but if you are able to provide help or even a solution using any other SDK or pure JSON/REST, I'm happy about that as well.

This is my code:

```
Select-MgProfile beta
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "ChannelMessage.Send"

$attachments = @{
    contentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.messaging-announcementBanner"
    content     = @{
        #id =               "<Insert random id>"
        title            = "This is an important announcement"
        cardImageType    = "colorTheme"
        cardImageDetails = '{"colorTheme":"periwinkleBlue"}'
    }
}

$bodyContent = @'
<attachment id="<Insert random id>"></attachment>
<div>Hi all, ...</div>
'@

$params = @{
    ChannelId   = "..."
    TeamId      = "..."
    Attachments = $attachments
    Importance  = "high"
    Body        = @{
        ContentType = "html"
        Content     = $bodyContent
    }
}

New-MgTeamChannelMessage @params
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide the link to the documentation? In my provided solution, I will assume that you reference to [chatMessageAttachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessageattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0).

---

```json
{
  "id": "string (identifier)",
  "contentType": "string",
  "contentUrl": "string",
  "content": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "thumbnailUrl": "string"
}
```

*From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessageattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0).*

---

```json
{
  "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.messaging-announcementBanner",
  "content": {
        "id": "<Insert random id>",
        "title": "This is an important announcement",
        "cardImageType": "colorTheme",
        "cardImageDetails": "{\"colorTheme\":\"periwinkleBlue\"}"
  }
}
```

*From your powershell script.*

---

`content` is defined as `string`, **not** as an object. I guess, you have to stringify the json and add it into `content`.

```json
{
  "id": "<insert id>",
  "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.messaging-announcementBanner",
  "content": "{\"id\":\"<Insert random id>\",\"title\":\"This is an important announcement\",\"cardImageType\":\"colorTheme\",\"cardImageDetails\":\"{\"colorTheme\":\"periwinkleBlue\"}\"}"

}
```